# Register Multiple Assemblies to the GAC in Vista

Tags: .net, gac, gacutil

I've got a whole directory of dll's I need to register to the GAC. I'd like to avoid registering each file explicitly- but it appears that gacutil has no "register directory" option. Anyone have a fast/simple solution?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

GACUTIL doesn't register DLLs -- not in the "COM" sense. Unlike in COM, GACUTIL copies the file to an opaque directory under %SYSTEMROOT%\assembly and that's where they run from. It wouldn't make sense to ask GACUTIL "register a folder" (not that you can do that with RegSvr32 either).

You can use a batch FOR command such as:

```
FOR %a IN (C:\MyFolderWithAssemblies\*.dll) DO GACUTIL /i %a
```

If you place that in a batch file, you must replace %a with %%a

Comment: Works great! For uninstalling, you can use this: FOR %a IN (C:\MyFolderWithAssemblies\*.dll) DO GACUTIL /uf %~na

Answer (score 11):

Here is the script you would put into a batch file to register all of the files in the current directory with Gacutil. You don't need to put it in a batch file (you can just copy/paste it to a Command Prompt) to do it.

```
FOR %1 IN (*) DO Gacutil /i %1
```

Edit: Bah, sorry I was late. I didn't see the previous post when I posted mine.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> gacutil /il YourPathTo_A_TextFile.txt

switch, if you have dlls in multiple different folders. Otherwise go with the `for ... in` loop mentioned by Euro.

The text file should contain a list of assembly paths (one path per line) which should be installed. The paths can also be different folders all over the system.
Run the command line as an administrator!

**Here an example of the YourPathTo_A_TextFile.txt:**

> C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
>   C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapter.dll
>   C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.Design.HostAdapterV5.dll
>   C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.DesignTime.dll
>   C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.EnvironmentalOverrides.dll
>   C:\...Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll

Comment: Enterprise Library = Ultimate DLL hell

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by Daniel answer but i would also add that we need to run Command Prompt as Administrator, and I also added a .dll to avoid trying to add other files

```
FOR %1 IN (*.dll) DO Gacutil /i %1
```